# Chrome Extension: Slow Loop / Breaking Pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, loops

Hi I've written the following extension for our company machines that should in practice remove any numbers from a list that is held on our webserver.

Whilst this works in it dramatically slows down loading of medium/webpages and chrome appears to look through the list of numbers (the favicon for example refreshes whilst this happens).

Any help or guidance for a better way of achieving the same result would be immensely appreciated.

[highlight.js]

```
// This array will all of the numbers to highlight
var numberArray = [''];

var UPDATE_INTERVAL = 57600; // Update after 1 Minute
// Retrieve script from storage
chrome.storage.local.get({
lastUpdated: 0,
code: ''
}, function(items) {
if (Date.now() - items.lastUpdated > UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
    // Get updated file, and if found, save it.
    get('http://webaddress/highlight.js', function(code) {
        if (!code) return;
        chrome.storage.local.set({lastUpdated: Date.now(), code: code});
    });
}
if (items.code) // Cached script is available, use it
    execute(items.code);
else // No cached version yet. Load from extension
    get(chrome.extension.getURL('highlight.js'), execute);
});

// 
function execute(code) {
try { window.eval(code); } catch (e) { console.error(e); }
// Run number replacement. 
numberArray.forEach(function(v){

var number = v; 
ve = new RegExp(number, "g"); 
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(ve,"DO-NOT-CALL");
});
}

function get(url, callback) {
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onload = x.onerror = function() { callback(x.responseText); };
x.open('GET', url);
x.send();
}
```

[manifest.json]

```
{
"background": {

},
"content_scripts": [ {
  "js": [ "highlight.js"],
  "run_at" : "document_idle",
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "css": [ "style.css" ]
  } ],
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'     https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
 "description": "Detect telephone numbers and remove blocked numbers.",
 "icons": {
  "128": "icon_128.png",
  "16": "icon_16.png",
  "32": "icon_32.png",
  "48": "icon_48.png"
 },
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "CLS Call Bar",
"permissions": [ "tabs", "storage", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
"version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing innerHTML of whole document for every number which seems highly inefficient

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(ve,"DO-NOT-CALL");
```

Instead you can use numbers in their immediate parent id/class as identifier like so

```
<span id="number-holder-{{number}}">{{number}}</span>
```

( it might already be like this as it is a common templating practice )

and in your content script do something like

```
numberArray.forEach(function(v){
    document.getElementById("number-holder-"+v).innerHTML = "DO-NOT-CALL"
}
```

If changing the HTML is not an option then do the regex replace on a temporary variable with document.body.innerHTML as initial value and assign it back after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this with thanks to Aman Verma for pointing out my replacing the whole innerHTML I've changed the following and its now very efficient...

From

```
numberArray.forEach(function(v){

var number = v; 
ve = new RegExp(number, "g"); 
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(ve,"DO-NOT-CALL");
});
```

To

```
numberArray.forEach(function(v){

var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT),
textNode;

while(textNode = treeWalker.nextNode()) {
if(textNode.parentElement.tagName !== 'SCRIPT') {
textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.replace(v, "DO NOT CALL THIS NUMBER");
  }
 }
});
```